# Opencv:calibrate camera and undistortion of image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I use the python calibrate.py script, which is part of the opencv example, to study the opencv camera calibrate algorithm.

I did only some small modification in the script that the undistorted image is always stored with the same picture size as from the input image.

If I use as input image one of the pictures that is provided by opencv the result is as expected. The undistorted image is generated as expected.

But if I use my own picture, I got the following results:

Sorry, can't upload my input picture (picture has the same size), due to few reputations:-(

[Picture with detected corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u4PA.png)
[Undistorted Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1gFl.png)
The output is as follows:

```
RMS: 0.121159225738
camera matrix:
      [[ 163.23957898    0.          322.26349617]
      [   0.          216.31952935  234.94645994]
      [   0.            0.            1.        ]]
      distortion coefficients:  [-0.08196739  0.03332906  0.01195436   0.00803256 -0.02955244]

      x: (0, 0, 0, 0)
      y 0
      w 0
      h 0
```

I already read in this forum that in such a case the distortion coefficients should be overwritten, but I couldn't understand why? 
And I did already some tests with manipulation of such value but I couldn't find a setup which shows an undistorted image using all pixels of the input image and black parts.

All hints are really appreciated!!

THANX!!

Comment: use multiple images and be sure to cover nearly the whole image over all those images. From my experience the calibration solving optimization will only optimize the covered regions, so everything around it might get very strong distortions (while the covered regions are quite straight undistorted).

Answer (score 0):

In your camera matrix, it is strange to have fx (163.2395) and fy (216.3195) being very different. Usually they should be very close as long as you are using square-pixel sensors which is 99% of the cases when using digital cameras.

In your pictures, the grid actually doesn't look like square. Please make sure your checker board print has square grids as it is a requirement of opencv's calibration.

Comment: Thank for your support!!! I just take more pictures (nearly 150) and run the test again. The result is better than before, but unfortunately the distortion doesn't satisfy me.

Comment: Thank for your support!!! I just take more pictures (nearly 150) and run the test again. The result is better than before, but unfortunately the distortion doesn't satisfy me. The corners of the chessboard are still not straigth. The FOV is about 120° and I found that opencv also supports fisheye calibration, but I don't find any information what the recommandition is to use fisheye calibration or "normal calibration"? Do you have some other suggestion that can improve my result ? THANX again!!